# Annotated Router is provided byte[] as parameter rather than POJO

Tags: spring-integration

I am using

**Spring Integration 4.1.2.RELEASE**

I am attempting to configure a payload router via annotations. However, I am receiving a byte[] as the method parameter rather than a message POJO. I tried to model my solution as advised in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27485545/291612), however the answer uses a native type as the message whereas I am hoping to use a POJO. What am I doing wrong in my auditPayloadRouter configuration in the configuration code below?

**Annotation in question:**

```
    @Router(inputChannel="auditRoutingChannel", autoStartup="true",
        channelMappings= 
         {"com.company.data.model.shared.AccountAudit=audit.account",
          "com.company.data.model.shared.BlacklistAudit=audit.blacklist",
          "com.company.data.model.shared.MediaAudit=audit.item"})
    public String  auditPayloadRouter(Object o)
```

**Full configuration:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class AuditConfig2 {

    @Autowired
    AuditMessagingOperations auditMessagingOperations;

    private Queue auditQueue;
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public void setAuditQueue(Queue auditQueue) {
        this.auditQueue = auditQueue;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setConnectionFactory (ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpInboundChannelAdapter amqpInboundChannelAdapter(
        @Qualifier("jsonMessageConverter") MessageConverter messageConverter
        , MessageChannel errorChannel) {

        SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer =
            new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
        listenerContainer.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);
        listenerContainer.setAutoStartup(true);
        listenerContainer.setConcurrentConsumers(1);
        listenerContainer.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
        listenerContainer.setQueues(auditQueue);
        listenerContainer.setChannelTransacted(false);
        listenerContainer.setPrefetchCount(100);

        AmqpInboundChannelAdapter a = new
            AmqpInboundChannelAdapter(listenerContainer);
        a.setAutoStartup(true);
        a.setErrorChannel(errorChannel);
        a.setOutputChannel(auditRoutingChannel());
        return a;
    }

    @Bean(name="auditRoutingChannel")
    public MessageChannel auditRoutingChannel() {
        DirectChannel c = new DirectChannel();
        c.setComponentName("auditRoutingChannel");
        c.setBeanName("auditRoutingChannel");
        return c;
    }

    @Router(inputChannel="auditRoutingChannel", autoStartup="true",
        channelMappings= 
         {"com.company.data.model.shared.AccountAudit=audit.account",
          "com.company.data.model.shared.BlacklistAudit=audit.blacklist",
          "com.company.data.model.shared.MediaAudit=audit.item"})
    public String  auditPayloadRouter(Object o) {
        if (o == null) {
            return "errorChannel";
        }
        //DEBUG - Print out the unexpected byte[]
        String out = null;
        try {
            out = new String((byte[])o, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println(out);
        if (o instanceof AccountAudit ||
            o instanceof BlacklistAudit ||
            o instanceof MediaAudit) {

            return o.getClass().getName();
        }
        return "nullChannel";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON message converter will only convert the json if the `content_type` message property contains `json` - such as `application/json`.

Otherwise, the payload remains as a `byte[]`.

You will see a warning log in this case.

```
log.warn("Could not convert incoming message with content-type ["
    + contentType + "]");
```

Comment: I am not observing that log message.  I should note that I am replacing a working XML configuration for this, and the XML version is handling the routing properly.  There are folks on the project that prefer the annotation style for configuration, therefore I am in the process of converting our Spring Integration configurations.

Comment: I think I found the issue on this.  I verified that the AMQP headers contained content_type: application/json, so I started looking elsewhere.  It turns out that I needed to set the messageConverter on both the SimpleMessageListenerContainer and the AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.